# How to sort String (more than 2 variables) alphabetically using compareTo() method?

Tags: java, sorting, compareto

I can't figure it out how to sort Strings (more than 2) using compareTo() method. For 2 I'm doing this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

String name1 = input.nextLine();
String name2 = input.nextLine();

if(name1.compareTo(name2) < 0)
{
    System.out.println(name1 + "\n" + name2);
}
else
{
    System.out.println(name2 + "\n" + name1);
}
```

But what if I need sort more data from the users?
Thanks.

Comment: You need to put the strings into a `Collection` (e.g. `ArrayList`) which you then sort.

Comment: Is it a hard coded number of strings, like, the users enters 5 strings, and you want to sort them, or is it a variable number of strings, like *n* strings and you want to sort them?

Comment: @aioobe Yes, exact number of strings must be sorted.

Comment: @MickMnemonic yes, I know. but I need  to do it without an array. There are exact number of strings that must be sorted using compareTo().

Comment: See the edit on my answer for specific number of strings

Comment: Do you mean without arrays or lists or any other collection? just the initial variables? If yes, can someone create temp variables? Also, do you a priori know the total number of Strings to compare?

Comment: I suggest you do `String[] strs = { name1, name2, ..., name5}; Arrays.sort(strs); name1 = strs[0]; name2 = strs[1]; ...; name5 = strs[4];`

Comment: @KonstantinosChalkias yes, as I said above there exact number (3) of any Strings from users.

Comment: @aioobe "arrays" is the topic of the next class :) for this issue we have to use only very basic things. anyway thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works without using arrays, lists or any other `Collection`, assuming you a priori know the number of Strings to be compared. This will compare 5 `String` values:

```
//use a max value for comparisons
private static final String MAX_STRING = String.valueOf(Character.MAX_VALUE); 

public static void compareMe(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e) {
    if (a.compareTo(b) <= 0) {
        if (a.compareTo(c) <= 0) {
            if (a.compareTo(d) <= 0) {
                if (a.compareTo(e) <= 0) {
                    if (a != MAX_STRING) {
                        System.out.println(a);
                        a = MAX_STRING;
                    } else {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                //swap (a,e)
                compareMe(e, b, c, d, a);
            } else {
                //swap (a,d)
                compareMe(d, b, c, a, e);
            }
        } else {
            //swap (a,c)
            compareMe(c, b, a, d, e);
        }
    } else {
        //swap (a,b)
        compareMe(b, a, c, d, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've done this:  if(a.compareTo(b) < 0 && a.compareTo(c) < 0 && b.compareTo(c) < 0)
  {
   System.out.print( a + "\n" + b + "\n" + c);
  }
  else if(a.compareTo(b) < 0 && a.compareTo(c) < 0 && c.compareTo(b) < 0)
  {
   System.out.println( a + "\n" + c + "\n" + b);
and so on for 3 variables. I'm not familiar with making my own functions yet. So Im using what I know, just very basic things.   Anyway, thanks for the clue.

Comment: just ensure you're checking for equality too

Answer (score 0):

Like Mick Mnemonic says, use Java's Collections classes and functionality.  E.g.:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

//This should be a do-while list
list.add(input.nextLine());
list.add(input.nextLine());

Collections.sort(list);

for(String s: list) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

This will sort the list ass follows: "*Sorts the specified list into ascending order, according to the natural ordering of its elements.*" - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html

No compareTo required.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example piece of code which will allow you to add multiple strings to a list and then sort them using Java's default comparator.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        boolean continueLoop = true;
        List<String> myStringList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please eneter a string");
        myStringList.add(input.nextLine());
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Please eneter a second string");
        myStringList.add(input.nextLine());
        System.out.println();

        while(continueLoop) {

            System.out.println("Would you like to add another string");
            System.out.println("Enter Yes to add another string");
            System.out.println("Enter No to sort the strings");
            System.out.println();
            String yesOrNo = input.nextLine();
            if(yesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Please enter another string");
                myStringList.add(input.nextLine());
                System.out.println();
            } else {
                continueLoop = false;
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(myStringList);

        System.out.println("Sorted Strings");
        for(String s : myStringList) {
            System.out.println("  " + s);
        }
    }
}
```

If your strings contain numbers and you want to sort them properly I would suggest taking a look at [this comparator](http://www.davekoelle.com/files/AlphanumComparator.java) since it has been designed to do that. To implement this you would use this method; [Collection.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-).

```
Collections.sort(myStringList, new AlphanumComparator());
```

**Edit**

For a specific number of strings you could use the following code

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        boolean continueLoop = true;
        List<String> myStringList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please eneter how many strings you will enter");
        int j = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        System.out.println();

        for(int i=0;i<j;i++) {
            System.out.println("Please eneter a string");
            myStringList.add(input.nextLine());
            System.out.println();
        }

        Collections.sort(myStringList);

        System.out.println("Sorted Strings");
        for(String s : myStringList) {
            System.out.println("  " + s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java, if you want to sort many string items, you should put them into a container, usually is a string list(also can use array).

Talk is cheap, show you the code, this is an example of sort 5 strings.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  //exact number of string
        stringList.add(input.nextLine());
    }

    System.out.println("before sort:" + stringList);
    Collections.sort(stringList);
    System.out.println("after sort:" + stringList);
```

---

update:

If you don't want to use Java collection framework's sort, if you really want to use compareTo() manually, you should implement a sort algorithm. Hear is an example that use [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) (But use compareTo() manually to sort is not the best practice).

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   //exact number of string
        list.add(input.nextLine());
    }

    System.out.println("before sort:" + list);

    //bubble sort start
    String temp;
    int length = list.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < length - 1 - i; j++)
            if (list.get(j).compareTo(list.get(j + 1)) > 0) {  //compareTo method
                temp = list.get(j);
                list.set(j, list.get(j + 1));
                list.set(j + 1, temp);
            }
    }
    //bubble sort end

    System.out.println("after sort:" + list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking probably for this:

```
    String[] arr = {"zsdsfc", "aazjkjf", "aabdd"};

    System.out.println("Before:" + "\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ){

        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }

    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ){

        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){

            if(arr[i].compareTo(arr[j]) < 0){

                String keeper = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = keeper;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("After:" + "\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ){

        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
```

the A.CompareTo(B) method returns negative number if A is greater then B, zero if A is equal to B and positive number if B is greater then A.

You can have a look at the [CompareTo(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/comparestrings.html) here.